# Recommendations of NLP for classifying sentance into tense forms

Tags: nlp, language-model, stanford-nlp

I have a dataset of tweets. I have to classify each tweet into it's tense forms like whether it's about past, present or future. So for that can you please recommend any pretrained NLP model or method for this task?